# Issues with looping array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json file:

```
{"places":[{"id":"1","name":"Balzac's Niagara On-The-Lake","logo_url":"http://example.com/store_images/new_82.jpg","website_url":"http://www.example.com","hours":{"monday":"07:00 AM - 07:00 PM","tuesday":"07:00 AM - 07:00 PM"}},{"id":"2","name":"Balzac's Port,"logo_url":"http://example.com/images.jpg","website_url":"http://www.example.com","hours":{"monday":"07:00 AM - 07:00 PM","tuesday":"07:00 AM - 07:00 PM"}}]}
```

Trying to loop and render the items on browser. Here is my code:

```
 class Dashboard extends Component {
  state = {
    data: ''
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(resp => resp.data)
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ data });
        //console.log(data.places[0].id);
        console.log(data.places.length);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    let content;

    for (let i in data.places) {
      console.log(data.places[i].name);
      content = <div>{data.places[i].name}</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h3>{content}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am able to see all the items in the console but not on the UI page.

[image]

Comment: Insert your JSON to this post as text, not a screenshot. Also, post the entire class. This is invalid since you've not included the second half of your render function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems here. First, the code is incomplete. So as it this has no hope of working.

Next, you have an array of places not an object, so you cannot use a [for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop. You'll need to map over those to produce the appropriate markup. [See MDN for iterating over various data structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Also, do not initialize `state.data` to an empty string. If you don't strongly type your code, it is good to at least provide an indication of what the type will eventually be. For example here you might supply an empty object (`{}`) or `null`. Setting it to an empty string (`''`) is misleading.

Lastly the JSON you supplied was invalid. Ensure your actual data source is correct. Here that meant correcting a missing double-quote on `name` property of the second field: `"name": "Balzac's Port"`. There are [several online tools](https://json.collaboradev.com/) for JSON validation.

I've simulated an asynchronous XHR activity here with `setTimeout`, but the idea is the same:

```js
function simulateXhr() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve({
        places: [
          {
            id: "1",
            name: "Balzac's Niagara On-The-Lake",
            logo_url: "http://example.com/store_images/new_82.jpg",
            website_url: "http://www.example.com",
            hours: {
              monday: "07:00 AM - 07:00 PM",
              tuesday: "07:00 AM - 07:00 PM"
            }
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            name: "Balzac's Port",
            logo_url: "http://example.com/images.jpg",
            website_url: "http://www.example.com",
            hours: {
              monday: "07:00 AM - 07:00 PM",
              tuesday: "07:00 AM - 07:00 PM"
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    }, 500);
  });
}

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null // or {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    simulateXhr().then(data => {
      this.setState({ data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h3>Places:</h3>
        {!this.state.data ? (
          "no data yet"
        ) : (
          <ol>
            {this.state.data.places.map(place => (
              <li>{place.name}</li>
            ))}
          </ol>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration of the loop, you're replacing the value of `content`. That's why on your page it's only displaying the very last item of the array.

In order to display all of the contents of your array, you must iterate over them inside your `render()`.

You can consider using the [Array.map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) inside of your render method.

Comment: Since it is an object, map function is not working.